# Broken Pipe Exception on Grails App

Tags: mysql, grails, broken-pipe

I developed an application on Grails 2.4.4 using jdk 1.7 and MySQL Workbench 6.3. It works for some time, but after some hours of the deployment i try to log in, it stops working and throws the exception "java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe".

```
2016-10-24 09:40:53,599 [http-nio-8080-exec-12] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - SocketException occurred when processing request: [POST] /login/autenticacao
Broken pipe. Stacktrace follows:
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3832)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2471)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:102)
    at sig.PasswordEncrypt.verificaAutenticacao(PasswordEncrypt.groovy:25)
    at sig.LoginController$_closure1.doCall(LoginController.groovy:20)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:198)
    at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have an external file with the following configurations:

```
   beans{
    dataSource(BasicDataSource) {
        url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_name?autoReconnect=true"
        username = "root"
        password = "root"
        pooled = true
        properties {
            jmxEnabled = true
            initialSize = 5
            maxActive = 50
            maxAge = 10 * 60000
            jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
            validationInterval = 15000
            minIdle = 5
            maxIdle = 25
            maxWaitMillis = 0
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 1000 * 60 * 30
            numTestsPerEvictionRun = 3
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 1000 * 60 * 30
            validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
            validationQueryTimeout = 3
            testOnBorrow = true
            testWhileIdle = true
            testOnReturn = true
            defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
        }
    }
}
```

I also added `port:3306`to `my.cnf` file and `mysqld : ALL : ACCEPT` to `hosts.allow` file on `/etc` folder.

Most of the properties were added after some research in another threads but it still doesnt work.
Can anyone help me find a solution to solve this issue?

**EDIT**

After trying the solution given by Dipak Thoke it still throws the broken pipe exception. It also shows the following error

```
2016-10-25 09:03:33,683 [http-nio-8080-exec-37] ERROR spi.SqlExceptionHelper  - The last packet successfully received from the server was 38,766,997 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 38,766,997 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

Should i change the "wait_timeout" value? Cause i already have the "autoReconnect=true" property

Comment: The reason was the database connections in the pool was not used for some time and the connection got closed, and when the application tries to use that it was throwing the exception.

Comment: Can you restart your appliation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125962/correct-way-to-keep-pooled-connections-alive-or-time-them-out-and-get-fresh-one  try this https://github.com/vahidhedayati/kchat/blob/master/grails-app/conf/kchatConfig.groovy#L22-L29  keep the autoReconnect=true enabled as it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the solutions that were presented here my application was always getting a broken pipe exception. I created a webservice with a script the runs every hour, that way the application never loses its connection to the database. Since then the exception was never been thrown again. Thank you all for your answers anyway :)

Comment: What type of script you have written for this ? what you have written in that?

Comment: a curl command in a shell script that runs every hour with cron in linux server

Answer (score 0):

You need to **c3p0** your project

**step :1**

Add this "BuildConfig.groovy"

```
dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile'

        compile 'c3p0:c3p0:0.9.1.2'
    }
```

**step 2:**

Datasource groovy:
Now your data source will be like this only remove the other things.

```
beans {
    dataSource(BasicDataSource) {
        **url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/db_name"**
        driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username = "root"
        password = "root"
        pooled = true
   }
}
```

For more info

[Do I need to use C3P0 pooling library in my (grails) web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803608/do-i-need-to-use-c3p0-pooling-library-in-my-grails-web-application)

[How do I configure c3p0 for a grails 2.X application with multiple datasources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532003/how-do-i-configure-c3p0-for-a-grails-2-x-application-with-multiple-datasources).

http://blog.nutpan.com/2013/07/grails-broken-pipe-and-cannot-release.html

Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Im gonna try it out today. In a few days i'll let you know if it worked :)

Comment: I tried to log in into the application a few minutes ago and the same exception was shown. Please check out my edit, i really dont know what else to do

Comment: I have some questions @TelmaCruz is this app in production mode or development mode ?

Comment: It's in production mode

Comment: Have restart your tomcat ??

Comment: Not recently.. last time i did it was last week i think

Comment: if your mysql connection is ideal for more that 9 hrs i.e no request send to database then connection pool get close so need c3p0 plugin which is use for pooling purpose?. so please restart you tomcat...

Comment: i restarted it now.. i added c3p0 to my dependencies yesterday so i thought it would fixed by now.. we'll see if tomorrow it will still be working

Comment: After restarting tomcat is your problem gone away ?

Comment: It only stops working during the night, some hours after the last access so i can only be sure if the problem is solved tomorrow morning probably.. for now i just copied the war file to the server again, restarted tomcat and now ill have to wait to see if it happens again

Comment: Still no luck, the wait_timeout error is gone but i still get the broken pipe exception

Comment: After all this time it still throws a broken pipe exception.. i've checked the links you posted but nothing seems to work. I don't know what else to do