# Exception in migrating from mongodb 2.4.12 to 3.2.7 in grails

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

I am migrating my grails project from 2.4.4 to 3.2.0. So i am also migrating my gorm-mongodb plugin to 6.0.0. Previous version of mongo i s 2.4.12 and current version is 3.2.7.

When i am migrating mongo version from 2.4.12 to 3.2.7 then there is an exception occurred in my domain classes.

I have two domain classes:

```
class ABC implements Comparable, Serializable, Validateable {
static mapWith = "mongo"

ObjectId id
String name
String value
App app

static constraints = {
    app nullable: false
    name nullable: false
    value nullable: false
}

static mapping = {
    app reference:true
}

public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    if(obj && obj instanceof ABC) {
        if (this.name) {
            this.name.compareTo(obj.name)
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
}
```

and another domain class :

```
class App implements Comparable, Serializable {
static mapWith = "mongo"
ObjectId id
// Double average
String type  // design / operating

static transients = ["name"]

 @Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (o && o instanceof App) {
        return this.name?.compareTo(o.name)
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
}
```

Exception occurred :

```
Failed to convert property value of type [com.test.Application] to required type [com.test.domain.mongo.App] for property 'app'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.test.Application] to required type [com.test.core.domain.mongo.App] for property 'app': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:603)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.grails.spring.beans.factory.OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(OptimizedAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:130)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.controllers.api.ControllersDomainBindingApi.autowire(ControllersDomainBindingApi.java:97)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.controllers.api.ControllersDomainBindingApi.initialize(ControllersDomainBindingApi.java:52)
    at com.test.core.domain.mongo.ABC.<init>(ABC.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:239)
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1089)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:408)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:516)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:509)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:485)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:62)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:252)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:55)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:374)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:363)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at com.test.Application.main(Application.groovy:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.test.Application] to required type [com.test.core.domain.mongo.App] for property 'app': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:576)
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an autowiring conflict in your application. I recommend disabling autowiring completely as it is actually bad for performance. Place the following configuration in `grails-app/conf/application.groovy`:

```
grails.gorm.autowire = false
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    autowire false
}
```

Either that or remove the `app` bean that you must have registered somewhere.

Comment: Hi @Graeme Rocher ,i'm facing problem this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214348/broken-pipe-exception-on-grails-app/40215198?noredirect=1#comment67775814_40215198 can you help me solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are getting that exception it is down to a misconfigured connection pool. Configure it correctly and the issue will be resolved

Comment: Thank you for help @Graeme Rocher can you add solution that question it's an humble request to you Thanks please....

Comment: I am getting another exception after applying your code in application.groovy . This exception is regarding :                                    DEBUG - Not running in Grails 2 environment, cannot de-register constraints. This exception can be safely ignored if you are not using Grails 2. org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.validation.ConstrainedProperty

Comment: That exception is at the debug level and as you can see from the message can be safely ignored.

Comment: @GraemeRocher can you please help me on this exception. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405521/exception-occurred-in-migrating-mongodb-plugin-in-grails

Comment: @GraemeRocher can you please help me on this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40758866/in-grails-3-2-3-with-mongodb-scandic-letters-are-encoded-wrong-when-saving-to